# Download all files from Azure storage account

Tags: azure

Is there any way to download all files from my Azure storage account instead of downloading one by one?? All of my files are shown on 'file shares', and there isn't seem to be an option to download all the files. I am not using blob services.

Everything seems a bit confusing atm to me. It's frustrating. I would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the latest version of Azure Storage Explorer, version 1.10.1, follow this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) to download and install:

[image]

After it's installed, open it -> nav to you file share -> select all the files / folders -> then right click, you can see the "Download" in the context menu.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! I have been trying to download-all using the online Azure portal, and apparently one has no option to download-all using the web version of storage explorer.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for pointing this out. Much better option to read, create token from here compare against the portal.

Comment: Thank you! For those wondering how to download all at once, there is a "Download All" option in the download dropdown button in the top toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Azure Storage Explorer you have the "Select all" option on the top toolbar. Use it, and then right click -> download.

Comment: Hi thanks. but when I select all, and right click, there is no option to download. only paste/delete/copy url or selection stats...